# Detect session lost in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In Express, we have noticed that sessions are being lost and customers are not being able to use the application properly. For example `req.session.OrderId` and `req.session.Customer` is no longer available.

We could not figure out how did that happen and what caused that. Is there a way to detect when `req.session.OrderId` and  `req.session.Customer` has been removed so we can log it how did that happen?

Comment: Maybe it's [expired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#cookieexpires)?

Comment: What's the maxAge you have specified?

Comment: This is most likely due to how you're setting your session, i.e. if you store a session in a cookie but the cookie expires after 20 minutes or when the browser is closed, then the `req.session` would not be available. So to figure out "how" and "what" caused it I suggest you look at the code that sets those sessions.